# Parsing particular text file java

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I have a logcat file from adb. the file is like follwoing,

```
  09-03 17:12:04.562   479   957 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity } from pid 1230
09-03 17:12:04.687   479  1030 I ActivityManager: Start proc com.amazon.mShop.android for activity com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity: pid=19164 uid=10158 gids={1006, 3003}
09-03 17:12:05.593   479   912 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { dat=?paramSuggestionText=cell%20phone flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 17:12:05.796   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity: +186ms (total +1s119ms)
09-03 17:12:08.601   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity: +3s925ms
09-03 17:12:08.601   479   620 I ActivityManager: Resumed Activity: com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity totalTime: 4037 ms
09-03 17:13:35.742   479   957 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=intentActionStartActivity flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.categoryBrowse.CategoryBrowseActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 17:13:36.007   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.categoryBrowse.CategoryBrowseActivity: +222ms
09-03 17:13:53.328   479   957 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { dat=?&paramSuggestionFilters=s%3An%3A%2C%3A4991425011%0As%3An%3A%2C%3A4991426011%0As%3An%3A%2C%3A5088769011%0As%3An%3A%2C%3A5263615011&paramDepartmentName=Programs flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 17:13:53.484   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity: +145ms
09-03 17:14:54.585   479   484 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 17:14:54.718   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity: +102ms
09-03 17:15:30.210   479   957 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:03:02.140   479   967 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=intentActionStartActivity flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:03:08.054   479  1005 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { dat= flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:03:08.171   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity: +105ms
09-03 18:04:24.937   479   967 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:04:25.046   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity: +92ms
09-03 18:05:00.554   479  5949 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:06:43.781   479  1019 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=intentActionStartActivity flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:07:12.984   479  1001 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { dat= flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:07:13.140   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity: +135ms
09-03 18:08:29.890   479  5949 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:08:29.976   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity: +81ms
09-03 18:09:05.515   479   961 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:18:42.132   479  1039 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=intentActionStartActivity flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.categoryBrowse.CategoryBrowseActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:18:42.359   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.categoryBrowse.CategoryBrowseActivity: +144ms
09-03 18:19:09.890   479  1030 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=intentActionStartActivity flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:19:17.406   479   485 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { dat= flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:19:17.515   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity: +97ms
09-03 18:20:58.500   479  5949 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/.search.image.SnapItActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:20:58.546   479   967 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/.search.image.SnapItPhotoCaptureActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:20:58.898   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/.search.image.SnapItPhotoCaptureActivity: +340ms (total +387ms)
09-03 18:21:26.156   479  1039 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:21:26.359   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity: +185ms
09-03 18:21:42.750   479   957 W ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{408f9da0 com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.barcodeSearch.BarcodeFirstTryTipActivity}
09-03 18:26:05.968   479   963 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=intentActionStartActivity flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 18:27:53.515   479   957 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mobileads.mraid.MraidBrowser (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:27:54.750   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mobileads.mraid.MraidBrowser: +1s218ms
09-03 18:29:12.726   479   484 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=intentActionStartActivity flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:29:15.609   479  1039 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mobileads.mraid.MraidBrowser (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 18:29:16.882   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mobileads.mraid.MraidBrowser: +1s261ms
09-03 18:32:41.750   479   967 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity } from pid 1230
```

Now I want to extract the activity name from the file. It is to be extracted from each line similar to this,

```
09-03 18:29:15.609   479  1039 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mobileads.mraid.MraidBrowser (has extras) } from pid 19164
```

or

```
09-03 17:12:08.601   479   620 I ActivityManager: Resumed Activity: com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity totalTime: 4037 ms
```

from this line I only need the string *com.amazon.mobileads.mraid.MraidBrowser*
other parts of the line needs to be removed. lines that does not contain *Starting:Intent* or *ActivityManager: Resumed Activity:* should be removed.

In the end I will have a sequence of strings like,

```
com.amazon.mobileads.mraid.MraidBrowser

com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity
```

and so on depending on their line number.

How can I achieve this? I can use string tokenizer but that is a tedious and inefficient process, regex matching or something similar will be better i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the regex

```
ActivityManager: (?:Starting: Intent.*?cmp=|Resumed Activity:\s*)(\S+)
```

Your wanted substring **will be stored in group 1**.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?321hu)

To use this regex in Java, you have to escape all backslashes, so it should look like

```
ActivityManager: (?:Starting: Intent.*?cmp=|Resumed Activity:\\s*)(\\S+)
```

The first part matches the string from "ActivityManager" till the part you want extract and the last part `(\\S+)` matches then a series of non whitespace characters and stores it in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

I know my approach might be not cute at all but it works. Would be one solution:

```
String filePath = "res/textfile.txt";
String line;
List<String> myL = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)); 
    while((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.contains("Resumed Activity") || line.contains("Starting: Intent")) {
            String str[] = line.split(" ");
            for(String s : str) {
                if(s.contains("com.amazon"))
                    myL.add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    for(String s : myL) {
         System.out.println(s);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**UPDATED:**
I just read through your post again and updated my solution. I missed somehow that lines including "Resumed Activity" or "Starting: Intent" should be removed.

Comment: I already did this using similar approach, but i was trying to find a better solution with pattern matching. This code works but not efficient. by the way i cannot know whether it is com.amazon or not, it is variable.

Comment: Does it mean you are searching for all lines where any activity, doesn't matter which one, is resumed or started?

Comment: yes, i want only the activity name, i sent the file from amazon, it can be any activity.